# Extracting users from manytomany field from model Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models

I want to extract users who follow specific user. I have two models here

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follow")
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, userq):
    usera = User.objects.get(id = userq)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(userp = userq).all()[::-1]
    print(userq)
    try:
        follow1 = Follower.objects.filter(following = usera).all()
    except:
        follow1= []
    try:
        follow2 = Follower.objects.get(user = usera).following.all()
    except:
        f = Follower.objects.create(user = usera)
        follow2= f.following.all()
    print(follow1)
    print(follow2)

    return render(request,"network/profile.html",{
        "posts":posts,"usera":usera,"follow1":follow1,"follow2":follow2
    })
```

How to do achieve this in views.py?

Answer (score 0):

If you need users which are followed by specific user:

```
Follower.objects.get(user = your_user).following.all()
```

If you need users who follow specific user:

```
User.objects.filter(follower__user = your_user)
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: it will get all the users which "your_user" is following, I want all users who follow "your_user". Sorry for asking wrong. i have edited question

Comment: i don't know what problem is but it is returning empty query set

Comment: Try with related name `User.objects.filter(follow__user = your_user)`, works?

Comment: No,it does not work . I tried Follower.objects.filter(following=your_user) . it worked but returned follower instances

Comment: You can get `User` ids from follower instances with `values_list('user__id', flat=True)`, but it's strange that my decision doesn't work for you. Can you add your views.py to question?

Comment: I have added view.py section